# SQL query search for a long list of numbers using Business Objects

Tags: sql, database, list, object

The company I work for recently transitioned us to BO from SQL Plus, to restrict database access. I used to search for a long (1000+) list of numbers in a database by creating a table and using joins, but I only have read access through BO, and that is way too many numbers to use a string. Is there anyone that can suggest the SQL I could use given these restrictions?

Comment: Table variable? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx

Comment: Are those allowed in BO? It seems so restricted. I will check it out though. Thanks.